# How to save the state of the EC2 instances upon connection loss from local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I need to train deep learning model in AWS EC2 instances. I can connect with the instances through ssh connection. After establishing connection, I run training among the instances. If my wifi goes down then i lose connection with the instances, as it shows "Connection broken pipes". So i need to again establish ssh connection, it's like restarting the instances again.

How can i save the state of the running instances so that after reconnection, i can get the previous state?

Answer (score 0):

Running command in background is one of the way to tackle this situation.
You can run commands using 'nohup' and it will continue even if your ssh disconnects.